# Where can I edit {{var firstname}}

Tags: theme, pdf, customer-address

Where in default Magento installation can I find the file of `{{var firstname}}` and similar variables?

Comment: I don't understand the question, what do you mean?

Comment: Are you talking about email variables?

Comment: No, I am referring to PDF variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just wanting to change the order that address variables appear in the customer address section of the pdf you can do this under `System->Configuration->Customer Configuration->Address Templates->Pdf`

The function `Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Config::getFormatByCode` will actually get the correct config from the code. In the case of the pdfs the code is `pdf`.

When rendering these formats the function is on the address model `format` and has a handy event that you can use to add or edit what will actually be formatted.

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_address_format', array('type' => $formatType, 'address' => $this));
```

In the case of the pdf the type contains the information saved in the config or defaults to the information saved in xml and the address object.

If you are simply adding new customer address attributes then once they are in Magento attached to the address then they will be added when formatting occurs but if you want to add your own or change the information then I would suggest that you should then listen to this event and add variables to the address object.

**Note the actual rendering happens by default in `Mage_Customer_Block_Address_Renderer_Default::render`**